# The colour of the footer text makes it hard to read

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta, footer

The text at the bottom-right of this page is rendered in semi-transparent white on a grey background:

[image: The only words visible in this paragraph are "cc by-sa 3.0" and "attribution required".]

The almost hidden text is:

[image: "site design / logo © 2018 Stack Exchange Inc; user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required. rev 2018.6.13.30743"]

This looks like a bug to me.

```
primary-unified.css
.site-footer {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

Comment: well looks like SO thinks those are the only words that matter :D

Comment: It is on black background in main for me and light grey in MSO for me. It looks like the image in MSO

Comment: you mean the horizontal line breaks? yes. I meant SO as the company in my first comment. Is that the confusion?

Comment: @SurajRao Ah, yes, that would explain it :)

Comment: Also I think the real culprit of this is https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369431/stack-overflow-meta-has-stack-overflows-footer issue

Comment: One should always read the transparent small print, hidden in the dark basement without stairs in a locked filing cabinet that's stuck in a disused toilet stall that has a sign "Beware of the Leopard"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed in the next build, thanks.

We overlooked changing that value when we creating the MSO theming for the new unified theme structure (on the other two sites that already have a unified theme, SO and MSE, the footer is dark).